# std::bitset hash function algorithm

Tags: c++, bitset

Does anybody know what algorithm thw hash function for bitset is using,

this is from website : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/hash

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    std::bitset<4> b1(1);
    std::bitset<4> b2(2);
    std::bitset<4> b3(b2);
    std::bitset<4> b4(8);
    std::cout<<b4<<'\n';
    std::hash<std::bitset<4>> hash_fn;

    size_t h1 = hash_fn(b1);
    size_t h2 = hash_fn(b2);
    size_t h3 = hash_fn(b4);

    std::cout << h1 << '\n';
    std::cout << h2 << '\n';
    std::cout << h3 << '\n';
}
```

and the output is

```
1000
4334672815104069193
16667047557902998627
2258353126044249582
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/hash

Also why doesn't it convert the bits to unsigend long and generate a hash value?

Comment: The C++ standard doesn't specify any particular algorithm. If you are interested to learn what your particular C++ library implementation is doing, you can examine its source code, and/or step into it with a debugger.

Comment: Thats is why g++ and clang++ give different results, ..., is it modifiable?

Comment: Is the problem that you actually want to minimize the values depending on the `std::bitfield` size? Maybe because you want to [sent them via MPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43263598/sending-bitset-with-mpi). Give us complete use cases and background when asking questions here please. Don't let me puzzle that all together from your profile. And please don't call people that spent voluntary time with your problems _arrogant_.

Comment: @DrJ All in all that is an interesting question.

Comment: ok, thanks for the clarification, dankeschon

Comment: @DrJ I hope placing the bounty was helpful for you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As [noted by Igor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43956125/#comment74945542_43956125), C++ standard does not specify algorithm, it [only](http://eel.is/c++draft/bitset#hash) [requires](http://eel.is/c++draft/unord.hash) that hash value depends only on object and will be same for the duration of the program: http://eel.is/c++draft/hash.requirements

> 20.5.3.4 Hash requirements [hash.requirements]
>   1  A type H meets the Hash requirements if:
>
> - (1.1) it is a function object type,
> - (1.2) it satisfies the requirements of CopyConstructible and Destructible, and
> - (1.3)
>     the expressions shown in Table 29 are valid and have the indicated semantics.
>
> 2 Given Key is an argument type for function objects of type H, in Table 29 h is a value of type (possibly const) H, u is an lvalue of type Key, and k is a value of a type convertible to (possibly const) Key.
>
> Table 29 — Hash requirements
>
> - Expression   Return type Requirement
> - h(k)  size_­t The value returned shall depend only on the argument k for the duration of the program. [ Note: Thus all evaluations of the
>     expression h(k) with the same value for k yield the same result for a
>     given execution of the program. — end note ] [ Note: For two different
>     values t1 and t2, the probability that h(t1) and h(t2) compare equal
>     should be very small, approaching 1.0 /
>     numeric_­limits​::​max(). — end note ]
> - h(u)  size_­t Shall not modify u.

Gcc's libstdc++ implementation of bitset uses std::hash: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/debug/bitset

```
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
  // DR 1182.
  /// std::hash specialization for bitset.
  template<size_t _Nb>
    struct hash<__debug::bitset<_Nb>>
    : public __hash_base<size_t, __debug::bitset<_Nb>>
    {
      size_t
      operator()(const __debug::bitset<_Nb>& __b) const noexcept
      { return std::hash<_GLIBCXX_STD_C::bitset<_Nb>>()(__b._M_base()); }
    };
#endif
```

https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/1cb6c2eb3b8361d850be8e8270c597270a1a7967/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/bitset#L1561

```
  // DR 1182.
  /// std::hash specialization for bitset.
  template<size_t _Nb>
    struct hash<_GLIBCXX_STD_C::bitset<_Nb>>
    : public __hash_base<size_t, _GLIBCXX_STD_C::bitset<_Nb>>
    {
      size_t
      operator()(const _GLIBCXX_STD_C::bitset<_Nb>& __b) const noexcept
      {
        const size_t __clength = (_Nb + __CHAR_BIT__ - 1) / __CHAR_BIT__;
        return std::_Hash_impl::hash(__b._M_getdata(), __clength);
      }
    };
```

LLVM's libcxx uses own implementation for bitset, xoring all words: https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/2c4b8af9aada61d83610330416eb8a39a8aa5494/include/bitset#L417

```
template <size_t _Size>
struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS hash<bitset<_Size> >
    : public unary_function<bitset<_Size>, size_t>
{
    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
    size_t operator()(const bitset<_Size>& __bs) const _NOEXCEPT
        {return __bs.__hash_code();}
};

template <size_t _N_words, size_t _Size>
inline
size_t
__bitset<_N_words, _Size>::__hash_code() const _NOEXCEPT
{
    size_t __h = 0;
    for (size_type __i = 0; __i < _N_words; ++__i)
        __h ^= __first_[__i];
    return __h;
}
```

and simpler variant for 1 word bitset:

```
inline
size_t
__bitset<1, _Size>::__hash_code() const _NOEXCEPT
{
    return __first_;
}
```

Comment: Can that be replaced by the OP for their own needs (read my comments on the question please).

Comment: @DrJ, How hash of bitset is related to sending it over MPI? User may provide own hash for some types  - http://eel.is/c++draft/unord.hash "23.14.15 Class template hash [unord.hash]"

Comment: Ask the OP please. I linked their self answered question.